# Can I Set "android:layout_below" at Runtime Programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Is it possible when creating a *RelativeLayout* at runtime to set the equivalent of `android:layout_below` programmatically?

Answer (score 484):

Yes:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.below_id);
viewToLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

First, the code creates a new layout params by specifying the height and width. The `addRule` method adds the equivalent of the xml properly `android:layout_below`. Then you just call `View#setLayoutParams` on the view you want to have those params.

Comment: why can't this answer be accepted ? It's a very good explanation.

Comment: Works for me. Used this approach to add a View ABOVE a view. This answer should be accepted right away.

Answer (score 154):

Alternatively you can use the views current layout parameters and modify them:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewToLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.below_id);
```

Comment: @EelLee It's pretty clearly another way to answer the question, which is why it has 11 upvotes.

Comment: This should have more upvotes than the other answer: to maintain consistent behavior of the view, we should work with existing `LayoutParams` rather than creating new ones. In fact, this should be accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 13):

While @jackofallcode answer is correct, it can be written in one line:

```
((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewToLayout.getLayoutParams()).addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.below_id);
```

Comment: this doesn't allow you to actually change the layout as you need a reference to the `LayoutParams` to set them with `setLayoutParams`

Comment: @Stef, I used this solution in one project. While jackofallcode solution is the only right here, I simplified it. But now I think shortening to one line is not good, because if any exception occurs, it would be harder to understand what operator raised it.

Comment: @CoolMind I don't really like shortening code to 1 line, it makes it harder to read, especially when casting is involved. Plus doing it my way allows you to make further changes :)

Comment: @jackofallcode, agree with you! Currently I also write in several lines, because when crash happens, it is easier to understand in what line an error occured.

Answer (score 5):

**Kotlin** version with **infix** function

```
infix fun View.below(view: View) {
      (this.layoutParams as? RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)?.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view.id)
}
```

Then you can write:

```
view1 below view2
```

Or you can call it as a normal function:

```
view1.below(view2)
```