# Trouble with Layout of my App

Tags: android, android-layout

Please help me fix it :

> [image: http://s27.postimg.org/bp1txpnoj/Capture.png]

xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".Main_Page" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the main.xml code of my app. The code has been changed from Relative to LinearLayout

Comment: Please post your layout code

Comment: So you add the Buttons via Code in your Activity? This is not the same that the picture you posted.

Comment: yes because when i select different options from the spinner the components should also change. If u can suggest a better way to do it plz let me know.

Comment: ya it is different, i have moved the spinner to the bottom of the layout for now but i need it to be displayed on the top.

Comment: Try to use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout or must it be a RelativeLayout?

Comment: and can u tell me how to change the input type of EditText programmatically.

Comment: LinearLayout didnt help. Now the spinner completely gets covered.

Comment: Just explain what you like to do. Then we can help you better.

Comment: What i want is the spinner to remain at the top and the components that i make like TextView, EditText, etc should be below it. Note: components other than the spinner is programmatically generated.

Comment: [RelativeLayout.BELOW](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3277302/2345913)

Comment: can the same code be used for LinearLayout like 'LinearLayout.BELOW'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LayoutInflator and inflate views to your main view when different values in the spinner are chosen.

//Main Layout

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_id">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/insert_Layout">
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

//Layout 2

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/layout_item_id">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, this is the inflated text :D"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:id="@+id/text_item_id"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

//call the main layout from xml

```
linearLayout inset_layout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.insert_Layout);
```

/create a view to inflate the layout_item (the xml with the textView created before)

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_item, mainLayout,false);
```

//add to the mail layout

```
mainLayout.addView(view);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, the code dynamically inflates layout 2 in the main layout.You can have many place holders in your main layout and inflate different layouts accordingly.   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: thx dude if u dont mind can u help me with this one to (http://stackoverflow.com/q/20280272/3026643)