# How to connect multiple xml files

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

My app needs different screens and each screen should be connected with each other. For example there are 5 screens, the main screen, 4 other screens connected to the main screen. The main screen contains 4 buttons to goto other screens and the other screens has a button to go back to the main screen. The problem is i cant get the ids of other screens. And do i need to create 4 .java files for the new screens?

This is the code for connecting main screen to others:

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
View one;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.total_assets);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    one = inflater.inflate(R.layout.total_assets,null);


    Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goback);

    home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_acc_soft);
        }
    });
```

total_assets is the second screen and actinity_acc_soft is the main screen.

(plz help newbie to android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ViewFlipper`. You just have to add all layouts to your main layout. And then you can go in your `MainActivity.java` through all layouts. [>ViewFlipper<](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)
But thats an older version of going through the views.

A nicer and more up to date method is using `Fragments` [>Fragments<](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

[Fragements Tut 1](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/)

[Fragments Tut 2](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Fragments_in_Android_-_A_Worked_Example)

[Fragments Tut 3](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)

There are many other tutorials and examples. Just google for `"Android fragments Tutorial/example"`

Comment: can u give a link to a sample code? as i am a newbie to android i dont know how to use fragraments in my app. If u could show it would be great. thx

Comment: or do u know any books for newbies that teaches these things?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use  and  tag in your main.xml file to include other xml files....

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

use `<include/>` in your main xml to include other xmls in your layout. 
OR 
Use fragments.

Comment: and can u tell me how can i use the components from second layout? and do i need to create a new class like total_assets.java ?