# Adding "below" to Linear Layout LayoutParams

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

My main (highest in hierarchy) layout is a `RelativeLayout`. Within it, I am programmatically creating a `LinearLayout`. It must have the attribute of being "below" `button1`. I know how to use `addRule()` to add this to `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, but `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` doesn't have that option.

Comment: refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277196/can-i-set-androidlayout-below-at-runtime-programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

You can not have below property to LinearLayout. At max you can give orientation type of Vertical or Horizontal.
e.g.

```
LinearLayout layout = /* ... */;
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
//OR
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `LinearLayout` is a child to its `RelativeLayout` parent. `LayoutParams` specify the child's layout within its parent, so in this case the correct `LayoutParams` to use for a `RelativeLayout` parent is `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.