# Android : Adding EditText one below the old one dynamically

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-edittext

I am working on an Android application in which I want to add `EditText` below an `EditText` which is at the first added in XML, and then added in code one below the other. Even though I am giving margin from top 200, the new EditText is appearing on top right. What am I doing wrong?

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1000dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_border"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/mittag_top" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
            android:hint="Menu karte datum..."
            android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/menuDate"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/menuDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menuDate"
            android:hint="Opening times..."
            android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstEntry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/openTime"
            android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"
            android:hint="Menu entry.." />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Java code :

```
public class AddStuff extends Activity{

    EditText firstEntry, date, time;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    Typeface type;
    int counter = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ocr_menu);


        type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/MyFont.ttf");
        firstEntry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstEntry);
        firstEntry.setTypeface(type);
        date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setTypeface(type);
        time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.time);
        time.setTypeface(type);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.menuLayout);

        firstEntry.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    addEditText();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void addEditText(){
        EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        editText.setHint("Entry number "+counter);
       // editText.setPadding(2, 200, 2, 2);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(2, 300, 0, 0);
        editText.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        editText.setTypeface(type);
        relativeLayout.addView(editText);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I add EditText below the last added EditText. Thank you.

*Update*

updated addEdittext()

```
public void addEditText(){
        EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        editText.setHint("Entry number "+counter);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int idLastChild= relativeLayout.getChildAt(relativeLayout.getChildCount()-1).getId();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,idLastChild);
        editText.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        editText.setTypeface(type);
        relativeLayout.addView(editText);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() > 5) {
                    addEditText();
                }
            }
        });
        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: You have to add the ```RelativeLayout.LayoutParams``` so that the EditText will be positioned below the older one. I suggest to use a ```LinearLayout``` with vertical orientation, this will add the children one below older one and so on.

Comment: set it below your `firstEntry` EditText programmatically, refer [Can I set “android:layout_below” at runtime, programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277196/can-i-set-androidlayout-below-at-runtime-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because  adding dynamic EditText in `RelativeLayout` so need to use `LayoutParams .addRule` instead of margin to align EditText:

```
    EditText editText = new EditText(AddStuff.this);
    ... 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

// get last child id from RelativeLayout
 int idLastChild=relativeLayout.getChildAt(relativeLayout.getChildCount()-1);
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,idLastChild);
  // set id for EditText 
 editText.setId(idLastChild+1);
 // set layout params
 editText.setLayoutParams(params);
 relativeLayout.addView(editText, params);
```

Comment: What after the first EditText is added, any other EditText will be added below it, as I will be adding a TextWatcher and adding more EditText below the already added one.

Comment: Just one last thing, how can I add an EditText below the one which is added in your code, something similar to what I am doing with TextWatcher and firstEntry, where I add an EditText, I would like to that same for newly added EditText. Thank you very much.

Comment: @WeareBorg: Your problem is not clear to me. because `relativeLayout.getChildCount()-1` will return always last EditText which is in  `RelativeLayout ` so we are adding new EditText after that. please explain more

Comment: Yes. So, the use-case is, the user can enter multiple texts in each of the EditText, but as the user starts typing in one, there should be an empty one added dynamically below, in which then the user can type and so on... Any doubts, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @WeareBorg: yes right , this is current flow when `if (s.length() > 0) {` condition is true then a new EditText added in dynamically below . Now what you want?

Comment: I have created a chatroom : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117072/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and--k  .. I have also updated my main post, have added the updated addeditText() mechanism, in which I will recursively call addEditText again, is it correct? Anyhow, any newly addded EditText is still at top right, not below the last child.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Enjoy. Tc. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a relative layout. Not LinearLayout. You should specify how position of your view depends on other views.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params
            = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) yourView.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.firstEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the params, but not assigning them to the layout. Do as follow:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(50,30); // Width , height
editText.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
public void addEditText(){
    EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    editText.setHint("Entry number "+counter);
   // editText.setPadding(2, 200, 2, 2);
    TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(2, 300, 0, 0);
    editText.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    editText.setTypeface(type);


  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

   newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.date);

    editText.setLayoutParams(newParams);

  relativeLayout.addView(editText);
    counter++;
}
```