# How to get reference to another view in attribute sets - similar to layout_below = "id" in relative layout?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-attributes

I am building a custom view. I am able to successfully get resources using `format="reference"`. However, I now want to pass the *id* of another view as an attribute and I want following restrictions on that similar to the relative layout.

1. This must be id or reference to a view - not *drawable* or *color* or any other value.
2. the layout with the id that is supplied must exist inside the current XML file.
3. I should be able to get a reference to that view and should be able to pass that view to other methods.

For example in relative layout, if you enter `layout_below = "@id+/someid"` and if `someid` isn't suitable it shows warning or error.

How to achieve this, please help.

**Update**

This is how i define the attribute

```
<attr name="myView" format="reference"/>
<attr name="dimen" format="dimension"/>
```

this is how I define view in layout xml

```
....
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
.....
<myPackage.mycustomView android:id = "@+id/myId"
     custom:dimen = "10dp" ///-- this one works fine
     custom:myView = "@+id/id_of_another_view_in_xml" //-- I am not able to retrive this view
     ....
/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277196/can-i-set-androidlayout-below-at-runtime-programmatically
i guess this could somehow will elaborate your problem.

Comment: Thanks but I don't find any relevance, what I am doing is creating my own custom view.

Comment: okay i understand. You are creating your own view type like relativelayout with such properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This must be id or reference to a view - not drawable or color or any other value.

When you specify an attribute for your custom view in an `attrs.xml` file for an ID, all you need is the `reference` type.

> the layout with the id that is supplied must exist inside the current XML file.

The red warning you see in Android Studio when you enter an invalid ID is a *lint warning*. If the ID does exist, just not in the layout file, it will still compile.

If you want to achieve the same thing for you custom view, you probably need to [add your own lint rule](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules).

> I should be able to get a reference to that view and should be able to pass that view to other methods.

Not entirely sure what you're asking. Once you've inflated the custom view and obtained the values from the XML attributes, you should have the ID reference, which you can then use in the custom view to do a `findViewById`. If that doesn't answer your question, please clarify.

EDIT: Code example, inside your custom view constructor:

```
mIdReference = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyCustomView_my_view, 0)
if (mIdReference != 0) {
    View subView = findViewById(mIdReference)
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: reference type also accepts color or drawable references. i already tested that.

Comment: Sure. But there is no "ID" type like there is for "color" or "dimen", so there's nothing else you can specify.

Comment: I am unable to retrieve id for the parameter I am passing in xml, I am not sure which method to use to get id that I am passing in xml

Comment: What have you tried? What does your code look like? What is not working that you think should be? Update your post with a code sample.

Comment: I am using typed array TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Drawer, 0, 0);

Comment: Then try{a.getDrawable() ... for getting drawable etc. but not sure how to get id to the view that I want to pass like custom:my_view = "@+id/view"

Comment: You need to show some code of what you're doing and what is not working. I can't keep stabbing in the dark. Update your post with the full code of your custom view that is not working.